# Why do I get the a.out 1:syntax error when I run Icarus Verilog simulation?

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, simulation, system-verilog

```vhdl
module round_robbin
    #(
        parameter   UNIT = 3,
        parameter   CH1_WT = 1,
        parameter   CH2_WT = 1,
        parameter   CH3_WT = 1,
        parameter   CH4_WT = 1,
        parameter   ADDR_WIDTH = 8,
        parameter   DATA_WIDTH = 8,
        parameter   CHANNELS = 4
    )(
    input                         i_rt_lt,
    input                         i_clk,
    input                         i_rst_,
    input       [ADDR_WIDTH:1]    i_addr  [CHANNELS:1],
    input       [DATA_WIDTH:1]    i_data  [CHANNELS:1],
    input       [CHANNELS:1]      i_wr,
    input       [CHANNELS:1]      i_rd,
    output reg  [ADDR_WIDTH:1]    o_addr,
    output reg  [DATA_WIDTH:1]    o_data,
    output reg                    o_wr,
    output reg                    o_rd
    );
    typedef enum logic [$clog2(CHANNELS)-1:0] {  CH1 = 2'b00,
                                CH2 = 2'b01,
                                CH3 = 2'b10,
                                CH4 = 2'b11} fsm_states;
    fsm_states ps, ns;
    reg [6:0] ch1_cnt;
    reg [6:0] ch2_cnt;
    reg [6:0] ch3_cnt;
    reg [6:0] ch4_cnt;
always@(posedge i_clk or negedge i_rst_)    begin
    if(!_rst_)
        ps <= CH1;
    else
        ps <= ns;
end

always@(*)  begin
    case(ps)
        CH1:begin
            if((ch1_cnt == (CH1_WT * UNIT)) && i_rt_lt)
                ns = CH2;
            else if((ch1_cnt == (CH1_WT * UNIT)) && !i_rt_lt)
                ns = CH4;
            else
                ns = CH1;
        end
        CH2:begin
            if((ch2_cnt == (CH2_WT * UNIT)) && i_rt_lt)
                ns = CH3;
            else if((ch2_cnt == (CH2_WT * UNIT)) && !i_rt_lt)
                ns = CH1;
            else
                ns = CH2;
        end
        CH3:begin
            if((ch3_cnt == (CH3_WT * UNIT)) && i_rt_lt)
                ns = CH4;
            else if((ch3_cnt == (CH3_WT * UNIT)) && !i_rt_lt)
                ns = CH2;
            else
                ns = CH3;
        end
        CH4:begin
            if((ch4_cnt == (CH4_WT * UNIT)) && i_rt_lt)
                ns = CH1;
            else if((ch4_cnt == (CH4_WT * UNIT)) && !i_rt_lt)
                ns = CH3;
            else
                ns = CH4;
        end
    endcase
end

always@(*)  begin
    case(ps)
        CH1:begin
            o_rd = i_rd[1];
            o_wr = i_wr[1];
            o_data = i_data[1];
            o_addr = i_addr[1];
        end
        CH2:begin
            o_rd = i_rd[2];
            o_wr = i_wr[2];
            o_data = i_data[2];
            o_addr = i_addr[2];
        end
        CH3:begin
            o_rd = i_rd[3];
            o_wr = i_wr[3];
            o_data = i_data[3];
            o_addr = i_addr[3];
        end
        CH4:begin
            o_rd = i_rd[4];
            o_wr = i_wr[4];
            o_data = i_data[4];
            o_addr = i_addr[4];
        end
    endcase
end

always@(posedge clk)  begin
    case(ps)
        CH1:begin
            ch1_cnt = ch1_cnt + 1;
            ch2_cnt = 7'd0;
            ch3_cnt = 7'd0;
            ch4_cnt = 7'd0;
        end
        CH2:begin
            ch1_cnt = 7'd0;
            ch2_cnt = ch2_cnt + 1;
            ch3_cnt = 7'd0;
            ch4_cnt = 7'd0;
        end
        CH3:begin
            ch1_cnt = 7'd0;
            ch2_cnt = 7'd0;
            ch3_cnt = ch3_cnt + 1;
            ch4_cnt = 7'd0;
        end
        CH4:begin
            ch1_cnt = 7'd0;
            ch2_cnt = 7'd0;
            ch3_cnt = 7'd0;
            ch4_cnt = ch4_cnt + 1;
        end
    endcase
end
endmodule
```

```vhdl
module round_robbin_tb;
        parameter   UNIT = 6;
        parameter   ADDR_WIDTH = 3;
        parameter   DATA_WIDTH = 3;
        parameter   CHANNELS = 4;
        reg i_rt_lt;
        reg i_clk;
        reg i_rst_;
        reg [ADDR_WIDTH:1]    i_addr  [CHANNELS:1];
        reg [DATA_WIDTH:1]    i_data  [CHANNELS:1];
        reg [CHANNELS:1]      i_wr;  
        reg  [CHANNELS:1]      i_rd; 
        wire [ADDR_WIDTH:1]    o_addr;
        wire  [DATA_WIDTH:1]    o_data;
        wire                    o_wr;
        wire                    o_rd; 
    round_robbin #(.UNIT(UNIT),
               .ADDR_WIDTH(ADDR_WIDTH),
               .DATA_WIDTH(DATA_WIDTH),
               .CHANNELS(CHANNELS)
              )DUT (i_rt_lt,
             i_clk,
             i_rst_,
             i_addr,
             i_data,
             i_wr,
             i_rd,
             o_addr,
             o_data,
             o_wr,
             o_rd
              );
    always i_clk = #1 ~i_clk;
        initial begin
        $dumpfile("round_robbin.vcd");
        $dumpvars("0,round_robbin_tb");
        i_rt_lt = 0;
        i_clk = 0;
        i_rst_ = 1;
        i_addr[0]=2;
        i_addr[1]=4;
        i_addr[2]=5;
        i_addr[3]=6;
        i_data[0]=4;
        i_data[1]=6;
        i_data[2]=5;
        i_data[3]=1;
        i_wr=$urandom;
        i_rd=$urandom;
        #5;
        i_rst_=0;
        #3;
        i_rst_=1;
        #100;
        $finish;
    end
endmodule
```

`iverilog -g2005-sv -pfileline=1 -E round_robbin.sv round_robbin_tb.sv -Wall`

I have no errors in using the above command.

After that, I used `vvp a.out`, then I get this error message:

```
a.out 1:syntax error
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: where are you getting the filename `a.out`? ... your source files have names starting with `round_robbin` ... the module also has that same name

Comment: @jsotola: This is expected.  The `iverilog` command generates a file named `a.out` when the `-o` option is not used.

Answer (score 2):

You should not use the `-E` option on the `iverilog` command line.  That prevents `iverilog` from creating the compiled version of the Verilog source code required for input to the `vvp` simulator command.

When using `-E`, the `a.out` output file is simply a copy of your 2 input Verilog files run through the preprocessor.  It does not compile the Verilog code into the binary file format required by the `vvp` command.  You didn't receive any error with the `iverilog` command because the preprocessor did not find any errors with the code.  However, you do get the error when running the `vvp` command because the `a.out` file is the wrong format.

Refer to the [Icarus Verilog documentation](https://steveicarus.github.io/iverilog/usage/command_line_flags.html) for details about the `-E` option.

When I don't use `-E`, I get plenty of messages from `iverilog`:

```
iverilog -g2005-sv -pfileline=1  round_robbin.sv round_robbin_tb.sv -Wall
round_robbin.sv:35: error: Unable to bind wire/reg/memory `_rst_' in `round_robbin_tb.DUT'
round_robbin.sv:35: error: Unable to elaborate condition expression.
round_robbin.sv:83: warning: @* is sensitive to all 4 words in array 'i_data'.
round_robbin.sv:84: warning: @* is sensitive to all 4 words in array 'i_addr'.
round_robbin.sv:89: warning: @* is sensitive to all 4 words in array 'i_data'.
round_robbin.sv:90: warning: @* is sensitive to all 4 words in array 'i_addr'.
round_robbin.sv:95: warning: @* is sensitive to all 4 words in array 'i_data'.
round_robbin.sv:96: warning: @* is sensitive to all 4 words in array 'i_addr'.
round_robbin.sv:101: warning: @* is sensitive to all 4 words in array 'i_data'.
round_robbin.sv:102: warning: @* is sensitive to all 4 words in array 'i_addr'.
round_robbin.sv:107: error: Unable to bind wire/reg/memory `clk' in `round_robbin_tb.DUT'
posedge clk
round_robbin_tb.sv:40: warning: ignoring out of bounds l-value array access i_addr[0].
round_robbin_tb.sv:44: warning: ignoring out of bounds l-value array access i_data[0].
4 error(s) during elaboration.
```

To fix the error messages, in the `round_robbin` module, change `_rst_` to `i_rst_`, and change `clk` to `i_clk`.

I get another error when I run the simulation.  You must remove the quotes from the `$dumpvars` line:

```
    $dumpvars(0,round_robbin_tb);
```